# automatically redraw from JPanel in other JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graph, jpanel, repaint

I draw two directed graphs in two different `JPanels` and when i click the button compile (RUN - COMPILARE) i need those graphs to repaint in one `JPanel`, any suggestions, tips, tutorials for that. I've searched but no results.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you draw them. If you use `Shapes` just paint them twice in the single (merge panel).

You can also override the merge panel's paintComponent() and call in the method with proper transform

```
firstGraphPanel.paintComponent(g);
secondGraphPanel.paintComponent(g);
```

Comment: graphs are drawn on two jpanels(area1 and area2) when i click a button who represents a node  and arcwith mouse over area1 or area2. i will try with your tip and return for more talk, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should override the paintComponent method of that JPanel you want to repaint:

```
@override
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    // paint your two graphs here.
}
```

When the button is clicked, call JPanel.repaint(). For example,

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) {
    pnl.repaint();
}
```